# SQL variable needed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to extract a variable from a table in order to use it in another statement.

the variable is the `id` of a board.

```
<?php 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM board") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
Print " ".$info['id']." ";
}
?>
```

This pulls and lists all the ids in the table.

I'd like to then be able to use the `".$info['id]."` data for a variable, something like:

```
$boardid = $info['id'];
```

Which I can then use in another statement:

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(is_following_board_id) FROM follow 
WHERE is_following_board_id='$boardid'");
$c = mysql_result($result, 0);
?>
```

Note the `$boardid` in the statement above.

However I'm having trouble with placing it in order to get the `$boardid` variable I need.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

```
<?php 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM board") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
Print " ".$info['id']." ";
}
$boardid = $info['id'];
?>
```

I'm still learning.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you expecting only one result row? Each row will have an id so it is quite ambiguous as to which row's id you want.

Comment: I'm only using this to get a variable for the `id` column, so I can use it for every id in another statement

Comment: no, their are lots of rows, not just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are using deprecated methods.

```
<?php 
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM board") or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data )) 
    { 
        Print " ".$info['id']." ";
        myOtherQuery($info['id']);
    }

    function myOtherQuery($id) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(is_following_board_id) " +  
            "FROM follow WHERE is_following_board_id='$id'");
        $c = mysql_result($result, 0);
    }
?>
```

`myOtherQuery` is called for each fetched row. This is not very optimized you might want to have a look at MySQL's [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) instead.

```
SELECT board.id 
    FROM board 
INNER JOIN 
    SELECT follow.is_following_board_id, COUNT(is_following_board_id)
        FROM follow 
ON follow.is_following_board_id=board.id 
GROUP BY board.id;
```

Comment: I'll give that method a try, although when I ran it just now the '}' after "myOtherQuery($info['id'])" was unexpected

Comment: Thanks. I managed to change a few things around with your code and achieved the desired effect.

Comment: missing semicolon; but you should really look into MySQL-JOIN

Answer (score 2):

```
$boardid = $info['id']
```

needs to be INSIDE the while loop to work :)

Comment: I tried this but keep encountering "unexpecting ';'" errors.

    while(
    $boardid = $info['id']; $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    {

Comment: That's because you put it in the condition of the while. Not in it's body ("inside the loop").

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `board` table only has one row in it then you can update your while statement

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
$boardid = $info['id']; 
}
```

Comment: This only calls the last created id in the table, not a unique variable which can be used to obtain every id.